# How to setup Appium for game automation

Tags: android, appium

You can test apps with appium to a considerable extent,it basically can verify in distinct steps,but if an app like a Game that contains continuous terrains and random data each time ,how can you verify those using Appium and Android.

Comment: @Emna ,the grammatical intent is correct and explains the question easily.However thanks for review.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the game from the outside we chose OpenCV image recognition library that is used for reading the screen buffer and giving X & Y coordinates as an input for the Appium script. OpenCV is really cool open source library that enables resolution agnostic image recognition, it is very customizable and can even recognize images that are stretched or at an angle.

The idea is to simplify the script creation so much that it includes only two types of tasks : Clipping reference images and defining what sort of click is performed when the match is found from the screenshot. No writing of complex scripts, compiling code or any other computer science skills are needed.